# Eliminating numbers from the sequence $1,2,3,4,5,6,7....400$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

BdMO 2014

> Let us take the sequence $1,2,3,4,5,6,7....400$ .We are going to remove numbers from the sequence such that the sum of any 2 numbers of the remaining sequence is not divisible by 7.What is the maximum number of integers in the new sequence?

We reduce the sequence mod 7.We get

$1,2,3,4,5,6,0............,1$

After crossing out $1,2,3,0$, we can actually see that there can be a maximum of 171 numbers in the sequence.Am I correct?Also,how can I write this solution neatly for easy comprehension?

**EDIT:** As it turns out,I was wrong.

Comment: You cannot cross out $0,1,2,3$. They pair up with themselves that do not produce a multiple of $7$

Comment: @Hawk,We cross out 1 because it pairs up with 6,2 because of 5,3 because of 4,and 0 because of 0.

Comment: So, we can cancel out $4,5,6$ too. The solution lies in seperation of $1(mod 7)$ and $6(mod7)$ type of numbers

Comment: @Hawk,we don't need to cross out $4,5,6$ because after we have crossed out $0,1,2,3$,we cannot pair $4,5,6$ with anything else.

Comment: I believe there are $173$ numbers.

Comment: @Hawk,there are 57 groups of 7 numbers from 1 to 400(excluding 400,since it pairs with 6). Since from every group,we are going to keep 3 numbers($4,5,6$),there are in total $57\cdot 3=171$ number in the sequence.Where am I wrong?

Comment: See my solution.

Answer (score 2):

In the set of numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$,We can either choose $\{1,2,3\}$ or $\{4,5,6\}$. Upto $399$ there are $57$ such sets. If we take the $\{1,2,3\}$ set, then we can choose the number $400$.Even after that we can choose a number which is divisible by $7$ since adding any multiple of $7$ to the numbers obtained will not be divisible by $7$. So,we can have at most $57×3+2=173$ numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.I always keep missing such tiny things  as how we can include 400 in the list and then take a multiple of 7 as well.

Comment: You are most welcome.